# Address-spaced identifiers(ASIDs)

Tags: operating-system, tlb

At the time of context switch, What is role of address-spaced identifiers(ASIDs) if on context switch TLBs gets invalidated?

Answer (score 0):

Storing ASIDs in the TLB is an optimization that allows for *not* flushing the TLB on every context switch. Instead, every process is assigned an ASID and its virtual ==> physical mappings are stored in the TLB along with its ASID.

There's some variance in how TLB coherence / flushing is handled by implementation, but as an example, the ARMv7 MMU uses 8-bit ASIDs. ASIDs 0-255 are assigned to processes (threads within a process, which share a virtual address space, also share an ASID). TLB entries for an ASID are invalidated when the associated process exits, but are not flushed automatically on every context switch. Obviously you can have more than 256 processes, so when all ASIDs are used, Linux uses a "rollover" scheme: the mapping of ASIDs to process IDs is cleared, the TLB is flushed, and ASIDs are assigned from the beginning again.

See [the ARM forums](https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/processors/f/cortex-a-forum/5229/address-space-identifier---asid) and [slide 5](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu//%7Ecs252/sp17/lec/CS252-Sp17-Lec17.pdf) from this computer architecture lecture for a bit more information.